# Converting java File to play.db.jpa.Blob

Tags: java, file, playframework, blob, multipartform-data

I have a Play 1.2.4 app that is the backend for a mobile app. I would like to upload a picture from the mobile app and associate that picture with a user. I have found lots of answers that show how easy it is to do image upload with Play *if the upload is done from a Play view*.

The incoming image is coming as a `multipart/form-data` POST request. The form field that contains the image is `file`. I created this method:

```
public static void uploadProfilePicture(File image, String filename, String token) {

}
```

In the model, I have a `play.db.jpa.Blob` object called picture. How do I convert the `File` to a `play.db.jpa.Blob`?

Answer (score 1):

You can map directly to `Blob`, and it doesn't matter whether it comes from Play view or not.

```
public static void uploadProfilePicture(Blob file, String name, String token) {
    User u = User.find("byAuthToken", token).first();
    u.profile_picture = b;
    u.save();
    /* ........... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
public static void uploadProfilePicture(File file, String name, String token) {
    User u = User.find("authToken=?1", token).first();
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        Blob b = new Blob();
        b.set(is, "image/png");
        u.profile_picture = b;
        renderJSON("{\"status\":\"success\"}");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        Logger.info("File not found when trying to upload profile picture");
        renderJSON("{\"status\":\"fail\"}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using BLOB in my data type on my model, instead i used byte[]..
it will be automatically converted to blob on the database..

You can refer to my sample model.

```
package models;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import play.db.jpa.GenericModel;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Entity
public class Memorandum extends GenericModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Expose
    public String id;
    @Lob
    public String details;
    public String filename;
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime datePosted;
    public byte[] attachment;
    public String subject;

}
```

My save controller

```
public static void save_memo(Memorandum memo,File attachment)
    {

        memo.datePosted = DateTime.now();

        if(attachment!=null)
        {
        memo.attachment = IO.readContent(attachment);
        memo.filename = attachment.getName();
        }

        memo.save();
        index();
    }
```

The byte[] will be in BLOB format in your database.